# How do I prevent the next url redirect from happening when a button is clicked?

Tags: jquery

I've created a single page that uses a button and anchor links to navigate. So when you click the button, it takes you to the first section ("index.html#one") and when you click again it takes you to second section ("index.html#two") and so on. But because each if statements meet the condition, every command fires up simultaneously. Now when you click the button once instead of going to index.html#two it goes straight to index.html#three. How do I prevent this from happening?

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
        if(window.location.href === "index.html#one"){
            window.location = "#two";
           }
        if(window.location.href === "index.html#two"){
            window.location = "#three";
           }
    });
```

Comment: 2 basic options:  for the 2nd / 3rd etc `if` ... add `else`  in front:  `if (href=#two)` -> `else if (href=#two)`.   Alternatively, `return;` within the `if`:  `if (href=#one) { loc="#two"; return; }

Comment: Alternatively, run them backwards - check for #three first, then #two, then #one so the subsequent checks aren't affected by the earlier ones

Comment: Or use a `switch`